# Integrating Zxing 1.7 into Android app

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

I have compiled the Zxing core.jar and I have already added it to my Eclipse project, but I'm having trouble while trying to use the Zxing libraries I don't know where to start from. What I would like to do is to scan QR Codes directly from the device's camera. My actual app does show the camera preview in a SurfaceView, but it doesn't scan anything.

My question is how to actually scan from the camera? Without using the Zxing intent mechanism, I would like to embed Zxing directly into my project.

I'm a newbie, I would appreciate any kind of help you can provide me: code, links , etc. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The project has complete source code for Barcode Scanner in `android/`. You can just reference this.

Comment: thanks for your help, yes I know I can use the code but is there anything like a manual? Or something I don't know which classes are using for having the scanner work with the device's camera.

Comment: The supported mechanism is via Intents. If you're copying source code you're more on your own with the javadoc. We discourage treating `android/` like a library since it isn't.

Comment: @SeanOwen just short question.. I read wiki but is it not quite clear for me if ZXing source can be used in comercial product as r4ul90 asked in his question? so not as intent but as part of app.. 10q

Comment: Yes but you need to follow the open source license (http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/LicenseQuestions) and can't copy the UI elements.